# Build docker image with same name

Tags: docker

I created a docker image using `"docker build ABC:1.0 ."`

Following `"docker image ls"`

```
REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID   CREATED      SIZE
ABC          1.0.  exxx12345  35 min ago   4.24 GB
```

There were some issues with missing directory so I deleted the above using `"docker image rmi -f ABC:1.0"`

I created another image with same name `"docker build ABC:1.0 ."`

Following `"docker image ls"`

```
REPOSITORY   TAG   IMAGE ID   CREATED      SIZE
ABC          1.0.  exxx12345  36 min ago   4.24 GB
```

It appears that the previously created image was never deleted looking at the time of creation and IMAGE ID. Please help me understand why docker is behaving like this.

Comment: Can you double-check the spelling of these various things?  Does the `docker build` command have a `-t` option?  The `docker images` listing has an additional `.` at the end of the version, `ABC:1.0.`; is that part of your `docker build` command and was it part of your `docker rmi` command?

Comment: A docker build will use the cache when nothing changes. Please provide a [mcve] including a complete Dockerfile, example change, and output from the build commands.